# How to pass object references through IPC or a memory database?

Tags: node.js

I'm using the `ws` module [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

And to reference the socket connections to a global `users` object is done like so:

```
users = {}
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server, wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(socket) {
   users[2] = {
      name: 'Bob',
      clientID: socket
   }
});
```

Now, if we want to utilize this socket object that is reference to this user, we can do:
`users[2].clientID.send('Hello from client ID 2');`

And this will work inside the **current nodejs process** of which it was made.

My problem is, when sending this data through the `ipc` or storing this data to `redis` or `memcache`, there is no way to reference that socket back to **this specific user**.

For IPC, `nodejs` `JSON.stringify's` the *object*, and with `redis` and `memcache` it stores it as key value string pairs as well.

If I wanted to transfer this object (with the socket referenced) to another `child process` **to be used**, how can that be done?

Comment: Which IPC method are you using? Will your processes always be on the same machine?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the communication between child forking using `process.send` and `child.on('message')` And yeah, same machine.

Comment: You can send a socket to a forked process like so: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_socket_object